# Shift-click doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I just had to reinstall Windows on my computer after a Windows 10 patch crashed my computer. All of my applications were uninstalled. After reinstalling Firefox, shift-click (and ctrl-shift-click) do not work.

It's very weird. My suspicion is that I accidentally changed a setting in about:config or it was changed for me.

I've tried opening Firefox in safe mode (i.e. disabling all extensions) yet the problem remains. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: They do not work - what is the behaviour?

Comment: just to know, what does shift-click do? I do not see any response from firefox when I do Shift+Click.

Comment: @RogUE see [FF documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks) for what are I believe default settings. Shift+click opens in a new window; I more often use ctrl+shift+click which opens the link in a new tab and brings that tab to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I use middle click to open a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick for me was changing the settings on a Firefox Add-On which had taken over the shift key. For others, consider opening Firefox in safe mode (which disables add ons) and seeing if shift-click works.